# Are comments that merely correct terminology acceptable?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, specific-comment

In C++, we say "data member" not "member variable". This led me to leave a comment underneath a helpful question which used the wrong term, along the lines of:

> The right term is "data member". The term "member variable" doesn't appear anywhere in the C++ standard.

I eventually stumbled upon the same question again and saw that it had been removed. The author didn't edit their question, so the comment must have been removed for being inappropriate.

Was this removal justified? Should I have made an edit instead, or what is the right approach to "correcting slang and colloquialisms"? I realize that this comment may appear like needless pedantry to some, but every question and answer on this website is meant to be like a wiki entry. Using the right words to describe things is important for consistency, and teaching people what search terms they should use elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps the user who posted the question saw it, understood, and flagged it as "no longer needed", as it *was* no longer needed. If you want the post to be correct, you should make an edit.

Comment: Given that you have 2k+ rep you can just make such minor edits and explain yourself in the edit summary.

Comment: @ThomA no, the question hasn't been edited. I've clarified this in the post now.

Comment: I'm saying *you* do the edit, @JanSchultke .

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily make such edits. Many C++ programmers do use "member variables", and will definitely be using that term when searching for answers. There's nothing wrong with using imprecise terminology that's a) commonly used, and b) not misleading. Both apply in this case, IMO. It would be a good idea to include such clarifications in answers if you want.

Comment: One could always edit a question/answer to include both: _How does X work?_ -> _How does X (aka. Y) work?_

Comment: @cigien I don't think that bad habits are made any better by being widespead. `using namespace std;` is probably the most widespread beginner's anti-pattern, and people correct it, every chance they get. Sure, using an inaccurate term is less damaging, but imo it's also not made any better by being a common mistake. C++ programmers searching for "member variable" will only find bad resources that use the same slang. They won't find it in the standard, or on cppreference, etc.

Comment: @A-Tech in this case there is a right or wrong though. It's like changing *"How does a pointy-thingy work?"* to *"How does a pointy-thingy (aka. pointer) work?"*.

Comment: The conversion rate for both comments and users is very low. Or in other words, comments are futile and users don't want to learn anything (for whatever reason). If you want to see change, you have to do the work. There isn't any other way around it.

Comment: related: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members

Comment: I would say this isn't a case of the comment being about correcting terminology, but more about how it is phrased. It comes across as pretty off-putting to me. You sound like a teacher correcting a pupil, not a colleague providing friendly feedback. C++ tag followers would have likely seen comments left by a famous C++ personality, where they correct the misnomer "implicit cast". Those comments are always phrased in a friendly manner, and I have yet to see them removed (since they do indeed provide a useful bit of information).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica that is a fair point, I could have phrased my comment in a more friendly way.

Comment: Huh, I learned something new today.

Comment: "*C++ programmers searching for "member variable" will only find bad resources that use the same slang.*" Maybe that is because the term is edited out of questions on top of good answers. Just because it's not in the standard, doesn't mean that the name is not useful. Beginners will search using terms they know, and "variable" they do know. Why not have some good resources with this term in it, that help them become familiar with proper terminology?

Comment: @CrisLuengo *"member variable"* is not an organic term. *"variable"* is, and *"class"* is, and maybe some beginners will think of it as *"class variable"*, but *"member variable"* is just something that spreads through bad tutorials, like `using namespace std` or use of `printf` in C++, etc. Compared to accomodating these bad tutorials, I see much more value in bringing consistent terminology to the C++ community. The compiler errors already say *"data member"*, cppreference does, the C++ standard does, high quality wikis do. Let's make it easy for beginners to use this ecosystem.

Comment: *"something that spreads through bad tutorials"* You're being too harsh. This is a *very* little-known nuance (haven't heard it being mentioned in my ~10 years on SO).

Comment: I frequently see Python questions that refer to arrays (not numpy) and tell them that they're called "lists", or JavaScript questions that say "dictionary" and tell them that JS calls them "objects". I've never considered editing the terminology in the question itself, should I do that instead?

Comment: I tried doing the array->list edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76493907/how-to-join-1d-array-to-2d-array). The OP immediately edited it back to the incorrect terminology. So I posted a comment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

TL;DR: The comment was likely flagged as NLN, and was removed as it was conversational.

---

Though only a moderator can confirm, the comment was almost certainly removed due to a "No Longer Needed" (NLN) flag being raised on it and when a moderator reviewed the flag they agreed and removed it. I agree that this was the correct action as the comment doesn't ask for clarification on the question, but rather advises the OP about the terminology used in the question.

Who flagged the comment as NLN we won't know (a moderator isn't going to disclose it), but it could well have been the OP read your comment, understood its meaning and then flagged it. That they then chose not to edit the post is irrelevant. Of course, it could be another user entirely.

If "data member" *is* the correct term (rather than "member variable") then a better™ solution would be to edit the question and change the term in that; you can then put the reason for the change in the Edit Summary box when you do the edit.

As a non-SME I cannot say if the term is correct or not, and there is already [one comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425142/are-comments-that-merely-correct-terminology-acceptable?noredirect=1#comment961498_425142) on this question that argues against the change. I do agree that if a term is well recognised and not ambiguous then such an edit may well be a bit "superfluous". If it's ambiguous, then a different comment would likely have been more relevant, as an example (for an area I'm an SME in):

> You refer to a 'field', however, tables don't have 'fields' they have columns and rows, and each column in a row has a value. It's not clear what you mean by 'field' in the question; can you clarify (preferably in an [edit])?

<sub>In comments [edit] is a magic link.</sub>

If the OP clarifies in the comments, you can then make the relevant edit.

Comment: This is an excellent answer and it really does address the question well; I could certainly imagine exactly that happening.  As it happens, [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76455800/why-am-i-being-told-this-method-could-be-const/76455842#comment134811171_76455842) is not currently deleted and has never been flagged (I suspect the asker misremembered where they posted it), but I don't think that particularly invalidates this answer.

Comment: @RyanM-Regenerateresponse it could have been a UI bug. I've definitely visited exactly this post a few days after making the comment, and the comment section was empty. Regardless, it is a good answer.

Comment: @JanSchultke it's also technically possible that a moderator had deleted it without a flag and then they or another moderator undeleted it on seeing this post, without saying anything (comments don't show deletion history), though that seems unlikely to me.

Comment: how could a moderator have done it if moderators are on strike. Wow, someone deleted my sarcastic comment too!

Answer (score 5):

The comment is entirely acceptable, IMHO, although I think that it would have been a better comment if it had linked to an authoritative reference for the terminology.

The problem is that some people would read that as a subtle request to correct their post and follow through, whereas other people will reply and thank you for the information without doing anything about it. (And other people will fall down the [rabbit hole](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DownTheRabbitHole) of the authoritative reference's links and forget what they were doing. Wait, no... I'm back.)

I'd say give the OP a chance to correct (maybe a day if you can't see when they were last active on the site), and then make the edit to correct (and any other edits needed, such as formatting, have a look at the title—as I frequently miss, grammar, anything else).

In the future, you may want to be more explicit and ask the OP to edit their post, to avoid any misunderstanding.